# Adding dynamic fields to a serializer in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a model

```
    class Event(models.Model):
        random_fields...

    class Registrations(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User...)
        event = models.ForeignKey(Event...)
        ts = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Now I want to fetch the list of all the events along with whether the user who made the `request` is registered in that event or not (`is_registered` field in the ModelSerializer of `Event` maybe).

This should ideally happen in a single request and not too many `database queries`.

What is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for reducing DB query. When fetching registrations from event, you can use `prefetch_related` to fetch all registrations at once(so multiple db query is not necessary).

So, for this first you can define the model like this:

```
class Registrations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User...)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name="registrations",..)
```

Then, you can define the **EventSerializer** like this:

```
class EventSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    registrations = RegistrationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # <-- getting all registraions via RegistrationSerializer
    is_invited = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
       model = Event
       fields = "__all__"

    def get_is_invited(self, obj):
        return obj.registrations.filter(user=self.context.get("request").user).exists()  # does not make any DB query
```

[SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) has been used here to fetch if user is being invited or not.

Now in the view, when calling the `Event` queryset, use `prefetch_related`.

```
# A minimal example

class SomeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        qset = Event.objects.prefetch_related('registrations').all()
        serializer = EventSerializer(qset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Hi, there is a typo in the custom field method, instead of 'get_in_invited' it is 'get_is_invited'.

Comment: This sounds good. As far as I understand, this method will load all the registrations for each `event` in memory. Am I right? If it does then is there a way to do this without loading all the registrations in memory?

Comment: Also for newer versions of django, I think `select_related` will not work for reverse relations. Use `prefetch_related` instead.

Comment: select_related worked for me in django 1.11. But it does not work in 2.1. There is 2 ways to do it to fetch data, one is either query database for each event or load these data in memory.